# Need to load a variable to Router Outlet

Tags: angular, routes

I want to use the same Angular application but depending on how it's loaded I want seperate components loading.

How can I get a variable in to my app-routing.module.ts?

This is what I got so far:

index.html:

```
<fp-app component-to-show="page2"></fp-app>
```

app-component.ts:

```
componentToShow: string; 

constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
  ) {
    const nativeEl: HTMLElement = el.nativeElement;
    this.moduleToShow = nativeEl.getAttribute('component-to-show');
  }

}
```

In app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet componentToShow="componentToShow"></router-outlet>
```

And in app-routing.module.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Component1
  }
];

const appRoutes2: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Component2
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  entryComponents: [FormForetagsprofil]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  @Input('componentToShow') componentToShow: String;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.componentToShow);
  }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What are your different ways of loading?

Comment: Added my intended loading of another component.

But my first problem is to get the variable in to the router-outlet I think.

Comment: If you want to pass the params in through the router & by extension through the URL, you can set it up in the appRouters:
```const appRoutes2: Routes = [{path: '/:somevariable',component: Component2}];```

Then you can either subscribe to the router's params or get a snapshot when the component initializes.
Not exactly sure if I'm answering your question because it's a bit vague.

Comment: try passing data in route config